# React recursion. Incremental string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I try to make string of hierarchy from object in my react app.
Object looks like

```
{ name: 'name1', parent:{ name: 'name2', parent:{ name: 'name3', parent: null }}}
```

My idea to make some state: const [text, setText] = useState(''); and incrementally add name to text.
This is my approach:

```
const categoryRecursion = (category) => {
    setText(text + category?.name + ' / ');
    if (category.parent) categoryRecursion(category.parent);
  };
```

In the finish I have text = 'name3 /' (only). But I expect to have name1 / name2 / name 3.
As I understand it is problem of asynchrony.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Most likely you need one or more `return`s in your funtion somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write your recursive function to `return` the string rather than calling `setText()` each time. Then you call `setText()` one time using the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using state `text` will only change the next frame. To get it to work you can access the current value of text by passing an arrow function to `setText` like so:

```
const categoryRecursion = (category) => {
    setText(text => text + category?.name + ' / ');
    if (category.parent) categoryRecursion(category.parent);
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I found it 1 second before :D

Comment: Noiceee :P. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner is making a recursive function to extract that string from your structure, and then using that however you need to in your React app.  For instance:

```js
const catString = ({name = '', parent}) =>
  name + (parent ? ` / ${catString(parent)}` : ``)

const category = {name: 'name1', parent: {name: 'name2', parent: {name: 'name3', parent: null}}}

console .log (catString (category))
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution:

```
setText((text) => text + category?.name + ' / ');
```